# Find an input to the system to achieve desired output

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

I have the following equation:

```
y(t) = x(t) and not x(t-1)
x, y are boolean variables
t is discrete time
```

which is an edge detector.
I further know that

```
y(0) = 0
y(1) = 0
y(2) = 1
y(3) = 0
y(4) = 0
```

and initial conditions

```
x(0) = 1
x(4) = 0
```

I would like to solve the equation so that i find satisfactory values for `x(1), x(2), x(3)`. For this example I expect one of the solutions to be:

```
x(1) = 0
x(2) = 1
x(3) = 1
```

I am Prolog beginner, but I think that Prolog is exactly the thing usable for solving tasks like this. I would write the expected output and initial conditions as facts:

```
y(0,0).
y(1,0).
y(2,1).
y(3,0).
y(4,0).
x(0,1).
x(4,0).
```

and the equation self as a predicate. How to rewrite the equation as a Prolog predicate and how to query for `x` ? Is it possible to obtain all soulutions? 
Many thanks for every idea!
Best wishes.

### After reading the 1st answer

There is a mistake in the constraints (if I use this term well).
The equation (system) as stimulated by `x(t)` will give particular `y(t)`

```
x(t):  1 0 1 0 0
y(t):  X 0 1 0 0
  t :  0 1 2 3 4
```

where `X` means "we do not know" because `x(-1)` needs to be known for `y(0)` computation.

The task is to compute `x(t)` for `t in 1..4` when `y(t)` is known.
`x(0)` and `x(4)` can be requested to have particular values or not. This only affects the number of solutions, but it is not crucial for the essence of the task, as I think.

For given

```
y(t):  X 0 1 0 0
  t :  0 1 2 3 4
```

there are imho two solutions:

```
S1:
x(t):  1 0 1 0 0
y(t):  X 0 1 0 0
  t :  0 1 2 3 4

S2:
x(t):  1 0 1 1 0
y(t):  X 0 1 0 0
  t :  0 1 2 3 4
```

If there are no initial/final constraints for `x(t)` there are at least these solutions in addition:

```
S3:
x(t):  1 0 1 1 1
y(t):  X 0 1 0 0
  t :  0 1 2 3 4

S4:
x(t):  0 0 1 0 0
y(t):  X 0 1 0 0
  t :  0 1 2 3 4

S5:
x(t):  0 0 1 1 0
y(t):  X 0 1 0 0
  t :  0 1 2 3 4

S6:
x(t):  0 0 1 1 1
y(t):  X 0 1 0 0
  t :  0 1 2 3 4
```

I would like to solve this even for longer series and for more complicated equations, this example is very simplified.

Comment: How can you consider S1 a solution: `y(4)` is 0, which is equal `x(4)` and *also* equal `x(3)`, whereas you specifically stated that `y(4)` must *not* equal `x(3)`. Similarly, if I understand correctly, S2 cannot be a solution because `y(3)` (= 0) is *not* equal to `x(3)` (= 1) in S2. What do you mean by "y(t) = ... and not x(t-1)" in the conditions above?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a constraint solver over Boolean variables or finite domains. For example, with SWI-Prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

edge(Xs, Ys) :-
        Xs = [X0,X1,X2,X3,X4],
        Ys = [_Y0,Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4],
        Xs ins 0..1,
        Ys ins 0..1,
        X0 = 1,
        X4 = 0,
        Ys = [0,0,1,0,0],
        Y1 #= X1 #/\ Y1 #\= X0,
        Y2 #= X2 #/\ Y2 #\= X1,
        Y3 #= X3 #/\ Y3 #\= X2,
        Y4 #= X4 #/\ Y4 #\= X3.
```

I get:

```
?- edge(Xs, Ys).
false.
```

So assuming I understood and modeled this correctly, your constraints do not admit a solution. When I comment out the last constraint, I get a unique solution:

```
?- edge(Xs, Ys).
Xs = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
Ys = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0].
```

It is clear from this that no `Y4` can satisfy the final constraint with these given `Xs`, since it would have to be both `0` and distinct from `0` (the final two elements in `Xs`). You can use `label/1` to enumerate all concrete solutions when there are still variables in your answers (which is not the case above).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. I edited the question and added more explanation. Your suggestion is definitely useful, but not exactly fitting into the needs. Best regards!